# How to return max number arr with the length of subArr?

Tags: javascript

`Products Array` has an array `property` called `subArr` and my goal is to return an array with the length of subArr which will include biggest numbers.

Array

```
const products = [
  {
    name: "car",
    subArr: ["4", "200", "599.4", "4444"]
  },
  {
    name: "tv",
    subArr: ["44477", "50", "579.2", "3232"]
  },
  {
    name: "glass",
    subArr: ["2121.1", "6347", "8867", "90.01"]
  }
];
```

My desired array is `[44477, 4444, 8867, 6347]`

I tried to map through the main array and the loop through the second one but can't figure out how to get an array with the length of `subArr`

```js
const products = [
  {
    name: "car",
    numArr: ["4", "200", "599.4", "4444"]
  },
  {
    name: "tv",
    numArr: ["44477", "50", "579.2", "3232"]
  },
  {
    name: "glass",
    numArr: ["2121.1", "6343", "8867", "90.01"]
  }
];

function getMaxFromArr(products) {
  if (!products.length) {
    return [];
  }
  return products[0].numArr.map((val, index) => {
    return products.map((prod) => parse(prod.numArr[index]));
   
  });
}

const parse = value => parseFloat(value);

const result = getMaxFromArr(products);
console.log("result", result);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you expecting to receive the length of this array `[44477, 4444, 8867, 6347]` as ouput ?

Comment: Get all the inner arrays to a flat array, sort it and take the first `n` items, n being the length of the `subArr`

Comment: `.sort()` and `.slice()` may be helpful in this situation. What needs to happen if the length of `numArr` varies between different products?

Comment: Why is `4444` the second item in your expected result and not the last and why is `6347` the last and not the second, going off the max values in the "columns" of each of your arrays, those should be swapped. Or are you trying to do something else (like the answers below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your current code you're trying to ["zip"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipping_(computer_science) the arrays within your products, but for each "column"/index that you zip, you want to grab the max value. That could be achieved by taking the max of your inner array with [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) the mapped numbers into that. You can remove the `parse()` method as `Math.max()` will parse the strings to numbers internally.

See your modified code below (I've also modified it to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) and the [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) (`??`), but you can keep it to use the same if-statement you had if you wish):

```js
const products = [ { name: "car", subArr: ["4", "200", "599.4", "4444"] }, { name: "tv", subArr: ["44477", "50", "579.2", "3232"] }, { name: "glass", subArr: ["2121.1", "6347", "8867", "90.01"] } ];

function getMaxFromArr(products) {
  return products[0]?.subArr.map((val, index) =>
    Math.max(...products.map((prod) => prod.subArr[index]))
  ) ?? [];
}

const result = getMaxFromArr(products);
console.log("result", result);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Approach:**

1. First merge the all `subArrs` by [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
2. Convert them to numbers using [`.map(Number)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map?retiredLocale=de)
3. Sort the `newArray` and finally [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?retiredLocale=de#:%7E:text=The%20slice()%20method%20returns,of%20items%20in%20that%20array.) them.

```js
const products = [ { name: "car", subArr: ["4", "200", "599.4", "4444"] }, { name: "tv", subArr: ["44477", "50", "579.2", "3232"] }, { name: "glass", subArr: ["2121.1", "6347", "8867", "90.01"] } ];
const sortNum = (a, b) => b - a; //descending order
const findMaxArr = (arr, sArrSize) => products.reduce((a, {subArr}) => [...a, ...subArr.map(Number)],[]).sort(sortNum).slice(0, sArrSize);
console.log(findMaxArr(products, products[0].subArr.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

- Get all the numbers to a single array using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) and convert them to numbers using `Number`
- [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array of numbers in descending order
- take the top n items using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const products = [{name:"car",numArr:["4","200","599.4","4444"]},{name:"tv",numArr:["44477","50","579.2","3232"]},{name:"glass",numArr:["2121.1","6343","8867","90.01"]}],
      
      topN = products
                .flatMap(p => p.numArr.map(Number))
                .sort((a, b) => b - a)
                .slice(0, products[0].numArr.length)

console.log(topN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const products = [{
    name: "car",
    numArr: ["4", "200", "599.4", "4444"]
  },
  {
    name: "tv",
    numArr: ["44477", "50", "579.2", "3232"]
  },
  {
    name: "glass",
    numArr: ["2121.1", "6343", "8867", "90.01"]
  }
];

function getMaxFromArr(products) {
  var BiggestNum = 0;
  var BiggestNumArray = [];
  if (!products.length) {
    return [];
  }
  products.map((value, index) => {
    var Array = value.numArr;
    for (let i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
      if (BiggestNum < Number(Array[i])) {
        BiggestNum = Number(Array[i])
        BiggestNumArray = Array
      }
    }

  })
  return BiggestNumArray

}

const parse = value => parseFloat(value);

const result = getMaxFromArr(products);
console.log("result", result);
```

Comment: The expected output is `[44477, 4444, 8867, 6347]`

Comment: oh sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I tried not to modify to much your code. You can read the logic in the comments:

1. Get the length of first `numArr`
2. Convert all strings in all `numArr` props to numbers and save them in a new array
3. Sort and slice

```js
const products = [
  {
    name: "car",
    numArr: ["4", "200", "599.4", "4444"]
  },
  {
    name: "tv",
    numArr: ["44477", "50", "579.2", "3232"]
  },
  {
    name: "glass",
    numArr: ["2121.1", "6343", "8867", "90.01"]
  }
];

function getMaxFromArr(products) {
  let allNumbers = []
  
  if (!products.length) {
    return []
  }
  else{
    // get the length of first numArr
    let subArrLength = products[0].numArr.length
    
    // convert all strings in all numArr props to numbers and save them in a new array
    products.forEach((prod) => {
      prod.numArr.forEach((n) => allNumbers.push(Number(n)))
    })
    
    // sort and slice
    console.log(allNumbers.sort((a,b) => a - b).slice(allNumbers.length - subArrLength))
  }
}

getMaxFromArr(products)
```